# Explain the answer to this logic puzzle

Tags: visual

Found this practice visual puzzle online. The top image is the sequence, and the bottom image (with 4 options) is the options for the final shape set in the sequence. The answer is the three black triangles. **Can anyone explain the solution?**

[image]

[image: Visual Logic Puzzle]

Comment: I'd pick the triangles because it's the most different. Other than that, there is little to no logic on this puzzle.

Comment: Yeah, I picked the triangles 'cause I thought maybe the left angle vs. right angle meant light vs. dark (the circles are not filled in while the triangles are) then I imagined the three bars on the last image as stretching the shapes into triangles. So, for example the left facing 3 bar one should be followed by three white triangles. It seemed to fit by process of elimination, but I can't see any direct logic.

Comment: I'm not sure it is a sequence so much as a set. Three of the answers are mirror images of the given patterns, the triangles pattern is the only one that isn't.

Comment: There is no repetition so I would select the triangles as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps..

> ..it is asking the question: What image is missing? Since all of the other images are present (whether they're mirrored or not) the answer should be the triangles.

Comment: I like the thought, Jaap Scherphuis thought similar in his comment on the question. When you account for the fact that all the other options are mirror images for one that's already in the set and the fact that only one choice can be made, it does seem to stand out that the triangles image is the only one that is _not_ a mirror of one of the given images.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if its correct but could be:

> the second image is drawn top view of first like the top view of first rods is circle and top view of the third image can be triangle(if rod not perfectly straight or looking from an angle).

or

> we can just consider the ends of rod; for first image its round and for third its triangle

and also

> If you see third image by half closed eyes(not sure whats the correct word) we can clearly see solid triangle!

Comment: The word you were looking for is "squinting".

Answer (score -1):

Foreword: I will be using the terms *image* for each of the large squares that contain the smaller figures, and *shape* for each small figure within an image.

It could be that:

> Each image (starting from the third onwards) has an additional number of lines to each of its three shapes, in comparison to its second previous. So, the third image has 1 more line to each shape than the first image. In the fourth image, 2 lines would be added to each circle's number of lines; the number of lines in a circle is one, and in a triangle it's three - which  2 lines were added this time.
>
>  This explanation would imply that the number of added lines increases by one on each next image; so, in a hypothetical fifth image, each shape would have 3 more lines than the third image.
>
>  Still not a perfect answer, as one could not possibly deduce the +1 line addition increment; as no previous images showcase this increment.

I could also argue that:

> In the third image, these little horizontal lines are actually 2 more for each shape - instead of 1; if we think of them as being one smaller line on the left of each diagonal line, plus another one on the right. Which would make for a consistent line addition of 2 each time. But I couldn't seriously accept this as an answer; since I don't see any solid reason these little lines could not be whole.

We also can't be sure if these are actually badly drawn circles, or just octagons.

Comment: I think this answer is a tad late

Comment: @Deepthinker101 And?